# Proper way to compile CompilationUnitSyntax

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have following code snippet

```
 var compilationUnit = SyntaxFactory.CompilationUnit()
            .AddUsings(SyntaxFactory.UsingDirective(SyntaxFactory.ParseName("System")))
            .AddMembers(
                SyntaxFactory.NamespaceDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("MyNamespace"))
                    .AddMembers(SyntaxFactory.ClassDeclaration("MyClass").AddMembers(
                        SyntaxFactory.MethodDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("void"), "Main")
                            .WithBody(SyntaxFactory.Block())))).NormalizeWhitespace();
```

However, it seems I cannot compile it with Roslyn when I use SyntaxTree from compilation unit directly - like that

```
        CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
           assemblyName: "MyAssembly",
           syntaxTrees: new [] { compilationUnit.SyntaxTree },
           references: references,
           options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary)
       );
```

I can't find anything better than recreating the SyntaxTree again with

```
CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(compilationUnit.ToFullString())
```

and passing it to CSharpCompilation.Create method. Is there any better way to compile CompilationUnitSyntax ?

Comment: what issues do you get when compiling like in your first example?

Comment: @Oleg Bogdanov `CS1547: Keyword 'void' cannot be used in this context`

Comment: On which line? This error looks totally irrelevant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the way you create compilation from syntax tree. The issue is in the way you create your syntax tree, specifically, the `void` keyword (as indicated by the error).

If you write this code:

```
SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("void").GetDiagnostics()
```

Then it will already report the error.

Instead of `ParseTypeName`, you can create a `TypeName` object for the `void` type manually:

```
SyntaxFactory.PredefinedType(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.VoidKeyword))
```

Full code that works for me (which is simplified from your code to remove unnecessary syntax nodes):

```
var compilationUnit = SyntaxFactory.CompilationUnit()
    .AddMembers(SyntaxFactory.ClassDeclaration("MyClass").AddMembers(
        SyntaxFactory.MethodDeclaration(
                SyntaxFactory.PredefinedType(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.VoidKeyword)),
                "Main")
            .WithBody(SyntaxFactory.Block())))
    .NormalizeWhitespace();

CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
    assemblyName: "MyAssembly",
    syntaxTrees: new[] { compilationUnit.SyntaxTree },
    references: references,
    options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary)
);
```

Comment: BTW, I found this behavior unexpected, so I created [an issue about it on the Roslyn repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/16191).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `CSharpSyntaxTree.Create(compilationUnit)`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I am still getting compilation error
`CS1547: Keyword 'void' cannot be used in this context`